Bank Statement for employment visa for Ireland under CSEP
I have two bank accounts: 1) my main salary account in which I receive salary and 2) my extra account that I use mostly. Mostly account # 2 is used for debit card for groceries, fuel etc. There are a lot of transfers between account 1 to account 2.
Should I declare my account # 2 in my application? I am not using 2nd account anymore, starting from this month.

The goal is and unfortunately should be to convince the case office by showing that you have both enough saving AND a source of income. I think you should declare the salary account that shows that the money comes to that account on regular basis AND if it shows enough balance. This will make the case officer realize that the above mentioned requirements are fulfilled. By the way, to make the case even more transparent you can declare both. And in the visa application, you can write a brief note describing the same what you mentioned here that why you have two accounts.

You should declare both, if only that you have nothing to hide in a second account.

What documentation does the application actually ask for? In this guide some documents are mandatory while others are optional. Typically for a work visa such as CSEP, the applicant’s own finances are of less importance than fulfilling the employment eligibility requirements. Assuming that any savings/income is legally derived, of course.
